# Why do we shift by three in RISC-V loops?

Tags: assembly

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-lwtStKeak&list=PL-Mfq5QS-s8iUJpNzCOtQKRfpswCrPbiW&index=4&ab_channel=AmirH.Ashouri) youtube video, the instructor explained some basic code in RISC-V assembly, but i didn't understand why in the first line, he is shifting i by 3. Why do we have to multiply it by 8??

I feel like it has something to do with the fact that LOAD IMMEDIATE operations can load values up to 12 bits only, but I couldn't make the connection.

[image: RISC-V]

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't provided any context of the code, we can just make assumptions.

**Assumption:** *save* is an 8-byte(or 64-bit) integer array.

**address of save[i] in memory** is equivalent to writing **base_address(save) + i * size_of_unit_element_of(save)**

Hence, to compute the effective address of save[i], we need to add i*(8 bytes) to its base address (which happens to be x25).

So, essentially, we store **i*8 in x10**, and **add base-address x25 to x10**, leading to **save[i]**.

Finally, we dereference it and store the value at save[i] to x09.

Comment: And this would be the same for every other processor in the world. Except maybe Intel processors which can multiply an index by 1, 2, 4 or 8 in a load, store, or load address instruction. So it has nothing to do at all with RISC-V.